# Running Adobe Dreamweaver on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wine, adobe

Is it possible to run Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 on Ubuntu 14.04 having installed it on windows 7 if I'm dual booting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It runs under wine 1.6.2

You can find information on this application and many more at the [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org) site.

source: https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=183